# method in Spring Controller is not getting called

Tags: java, spring

I have following controller in spring web application:

```
@Controller
public class MigrationController {

/*  @Autowired
    com.nated.app.migration.service.AddItemService Service;*/

     @RequestMapping("/signin")
    public ModelAndView signIn() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("signin");
        //MigrationTO bean = new MigrationTO();
        //mav.addObject("searchUserGet", bean);
        return mav;
    }
     @RequestMapping("/migration")
    public ModelAndView searchContact() {

        //MigrationTO bean = new MigrationTO();
        //mav.addObject("searchUserGet", bean);
        MigrationService migrationService=new MigrationService();
        MigrationTO migrationTO=migrationService.getMigrationItems("OTH");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("migrationPage");
        mav.addObject("migrationTO", migrationTO);
        return mav;
    } 
}
```

look in the method `searchcontact` ,method `getmigrationItem` is not getting called.

Anyone please suggest me some solution

```
    import java.util.List;

import com.nated.app.migration.beans.MigrationTO;
import com.nated.app.migration.dao.IMigrationDao;
import com.nated.app.migration.dao.impl.MigrationDaoImpl;

public class MigrationService {

    public MigrationTO getMigrationItems(String status){
        List<MigrationTO> lst = null;
        MigrationTO migrationTO=null;
        try {
            IMigrationDao migrationDao=new MigrationDaoImpl();
             migrationTO = migrationDao.getMigrationItems(status);
             if(migrationTO.getOthersFlag()=="Y"){
                 migrationTO = migrationDao.getMigrationItemsOther("Nap");
             }
             return migrationTO;
        }  catch (Exception exception) {
            //logger.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getMessage());
            exception.printStackTrace();
            //throw exception;
        } finally {
            //logger.log(Level.INFO, "getMigrationItems Ends");
        }

    }
}
```

this is service,will it work and i was putting break point at last line(return).

Comment: Have you make sure that your `searchContact` is entered?If not, post your config java class or web.xml

Comment: Does the rest of the code work? Do you receive the expected view for the request? Are you sure the MigrationService() call does not throw an Exception that blocks the execution?

Comment: u have not Maintain is it get or post ?

Comment: @Jaskey wat r u trying to say i couldn't understand,

Comment: when i m hitting in url(http://localhost:8080/nated/migration) then control is coming to searchContact  method and it comeing to a break point i have provided it 3rd line from below( ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("migrationPage");) and is is displaying migrationPage.jsp.

Comment: @, so what do you mean `getMigrationItems` is not called? Have you log a break point inside?

Comment: @A@Krishna by default is GET

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: @Jaskey I have putten one break point in getMigrationItems but control does not go there.

Comment: @Raju , post your code of MigrationService then.

Comment: We need to see that `MigrationService`. I'm also skeptical of exactly where you're putting your breakpoint and whether you're running in debug mode.

Comment: My guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null